# can't run Cyberoam Client on x64

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, internet, cybercafe

I got following error when trying to run this file:

```
bash: ./crclient: No such file or directory
```

when u download the client u get this 2 files : ( crclient  ,README)

http://download.cyberoam.com/solution/optionals/CyberoamLinuxClient.tar.gz

command i used : https://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=1870&Lang=1&SID=

uname-a : Linux qan-OptiPlex-790 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I gave it `+x` permission but no success

I can't use my internet. Is there any help please?

Comment: Which file and command did you use to run? Please specify.

Comment: can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l | grep crc` ?

Comment: when u download the client u get this 2 files : 
http://download.cyberoam.com/solution/optionals/CyberoamLinuxClient.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
sudo apt-get update
```

to run on x86

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

The above is adding 32 bit enviroment since the client is supported for 32 bit and you might have 64 bit OS

After that install dependancies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Then run:

```
./crcclient -u username
```